# Исправить функцию преобразования изображения в base64 по ссылке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть функция(не мной написанная) преобразования изображения в base64 из ссылки на это изображение.

```js
function convertImgToBase64URL(url, callback, outputFormat){
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'), dataURL;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        canvas.width = img.width;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
        callback(dataURL);
  canvas = null;
    };
    img.src = url;
}
```

Но с ней можно работать только таким образом:

```js
var pic = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/Logo_2013_Google.png';
convertImgToBase64URL(pic, function(base64Img){
$('#id').attr('href', base64Img);
   });
```

Что вообще никак не удобно.
Как исправить функцию, чтобы она возвращала значение, а использовать ее можно было как и должно?

```js
 convertImgToBase64URL(pic); //где pic ссылка на изображение
```

Пытался разобраться с помощью темы:
[Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%98%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6)
Но никак не получается. Я знаю, что мне надо вернуть значение dataURL но любое обращение к нему вызывает ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

чтобы прям вернула - это асинхронная функция из-за onload. Так что в любом случае надо ждать окончания её работы.

```
var resultDiv = document.getElementById('result');

function convertImgToBase64URL(url){
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'), dataURL;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.width = this.width;
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        resultDiv.innerHTML = dataURL;
        console.log(dataURL);
        canvas = null; 
    };
    img.src = url;
}

convertImgToBase64URL('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/Logo_2013_Google.png');
```

Comment: Блин, мне просто дальше необходимо это изображение в blob перевести. а подцепить никак не получается. convertImgToBase64URL(bg, function(base64Img){$('#nnic-e').attr('href', base64Img);});  задает вроде нормально, но следом считывая fota = $('#nnic-e').attr('href');
alert(fota);
 ничего не получаю

Comment: не видно как там это следом происходит. мб, на тот момент оно еще не изменилось, попробуйте засунуть в конец стека через setTimeout()

Comment: https://jsbin.com/befekidili/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: ну, тут или выполнять в колбеке этом же, или использовать MutationObserver и следить смену атрибута